# I can retrieve data but cannot insert data into the database in C#

Tags: c#

please help me. I developed an windows application using C#.NET. I configured my database connection string
in app.config file. The problem is that I can retrieve data but cannot insert data into the database. 
My code is....

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'database1DataSet.student' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.nameTableAdapter.Fill(this.database1DataSet.student);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["mycon"].ConnectionString);

        con.Open();

        String str = "insert into student(Id,name,num) values(" + textBox1.Text + ",'" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text + "')";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, con);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
        label1.Text = "Data has been successfully inserted";
    }
}
```

app. config file....

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="mycon"
            connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Please provide more details about the error and your code what you have written so far.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please provide us with more information. Are you getting error messages or logs? If so, please [edit] them into your question. Also, show us the code you use to insert data; maybe there is an error in it.

Comment: what does your error say?

Comment: I didn't get any error.

Comment: Are you sure you need to insert an ID value? Did you create this database?

Comment: yes, i created this database

Comment: Side note: your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). This is a security vulnerability. After you have solved your current problem, learn about SQL injection. To keep your application safe.

Comment: i can insert data when i use the connection string directly ie, Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=D:\C#Projects\myexe\myappp\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True

Comment: I assume the insert statement is correct as the conn string works when you define it locally... so debug it and see what the conn string is when you retrieve it in code.... if you have a named instance and it looks like you are using sql server... try changing your conn string to something like Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;Integrated Security=true; see https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing quotes, try surrounding your textblock1.text with single quotes like you did with the other two.

Comment: It did not make any change in my result

Answer (score 0):

Please be careful with the name of the table, I mean here "insert into **name**(Id,**name**,num)" ... this could create a problem, maybe try to change the name of the table or check if is corect.

Sometimes this can create confusion to SQL.

Comment: i changed table name as "student". But there is no result